# Call a function within a function display both within array

Tags: php, arrays, function, recursion

how do I call a function from within a function?

```
function tt($data,$s,$t){
    $data=$data;
    echo '[[';
    print_r($data);
    echo ']]';
    if($t==0){
        $data[]=$s;
        tt($data,'two',1);
    }else{
        $data[]=$s;
    }
    return $data;
}
print_r(tt('','one',0));
```

I want 'two' to be shown within the array like

```
$o[]='one';
$o[]='two';
print_r($o);
```

Comment: You are calling the function just fine, but you're not passing the data back out.

Comment: Also your first instruction ```$data = $data``` does nothing...

Comment: how do I pass it through?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function tt($s, $t, array $data = array()) {
    $data[] = $s;
    if ($t == 0) {
        $data = tt('two', 1, $data);
    }
    return $data;
}

print_r(tt('one', 0));
```

This is all that's really needed.

1. Put the array as the last argument and make it optional, because you don't need it on the initial call.
2. When calling `tt` recursively, you need to "catch" its return data, otherwise the recursive call simply does nothing of lasting value.
3. No need for the `else`, since you're going to append the entry to the array no matter what and don't need to write that twice.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one (notice the function signature, the array is passed by ref *&$data*):

```
function tt(&$data,$s,$t){
    echo '[[';
    print_r($data);
    echo ']]';
    if($t==0){
        $data[]=$s;
        tt($data,'two',1);
    }else{
        $data[]=$s;
    }
    return $data;
}

$array = [];
tt($array,'one',0);
print_r($array);
/**
Array
 (
   [0] => one
   [1] => two
 )
*/
```

Comment: Glad to help, though @deceze cleaned up the function, you should take that into account also :-)

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
 function tt($data,$s,$t){
        global $data;

        if($t==0){
            $data[]=$s;
            tt($data,'two',1);
        }else{
            $data[]=$s;
        }
        return $data;
    }
   print_r(tt('','one',0));
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
Array
(
    [0] => one
    [1] => two
)
```

**[DEMO](https://eval.in/180374)**

Comment: when i used this it compounded my other functions into the same array.